# Problem to draw a graph in circular way

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I draw a graph with the Graph function with the following manner

```
listSorted ={{1, 0}, 1, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, 2, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, 3, {3, 0}, {0, 3}, 0, {0, 1}}


    EdgesBody = {0 -> {0, 1}, 1 -> {1, 0}, 1 -> {1, 2}, 2 -> {2, 1}, 
  2 -> {2, 3}, 3 -> {3, 2}, 0 -> {0, 3}, 3 -> {3, 0}}

EdgesJoints = {{0, 1} -> {1, 0}, {1, 2} -> {2, 1}, {2, 3} -> {3, 
2}, {0, 3} -> {3, 0}}

    g = Graph[listSorted, Join[EdgesBody, EdgesJoints], 
  GraphLayout -> "StarEmbedding", PlotTheme -> "NameLabeled", 
  VertexSize -> Large]
```

I would like that all my vertex be located in a circle. The point 1 is located in the center. How can i do so as that all the points be located in a circle ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: `CircularEmbedding`...

Comment: Use the option: `Method -> "CircularEmbedding"`

Comment: Thank you for the help the option GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding" does the job. In fact, before it didn't work because i had already another option which should have made conflicts with this one

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if what you want is this:

```
PathGraph[Range[11], GraphLayout -> {"CircularEmbedding"}, VertexSize -> Large]
```

[image]